# protect NAS shared folder against cryptolocker attack

Tags: network-attached-storage, malware

I got a NAS with some shared folders, for access it a user/pass authentication is needed. My question is about how a malicious software (expecially a cryptolocker) can access to the network folder depending on how i open it.
For example...if i "mount" the network shared folder using "connect network resource" in, let's say, **x:**\ saving user/pass so the user don't need to insert them every time, when i boot the pc i find **x:**\ and i can access it, and i guess that the virus can do the same...right?
If instead i only make a directory link that points to the shared folder, and i must insert user/pass when i open it, what happens? When i start the pc the directory is not accessible until when i insert the user/pass for open it, so obviously the virus can't access it...but after i open the folder and i provide user/pass i can access the folder, but the virus? Can it "find" the folder and crypt the files inside it even if the folder have not an address like **x:**\ or **c:\something\somethingelse**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most cryptolockers can access any directories you as a user can, even if mounted only briefly. One of the best ways around this is to stop using your system and kernel to access your files, and get them through a browser using something like Google Drive or their hybrid Storage cloud. Your NAS may also provide an HTTPS based interface, which would work fine in most cases.